# Why am I getting System.Data.DataRow here?

Tags: sql, powershell

Im unsure as to why Im getting this because I have the same code elsewhere and there is no problem.

Thanks for your help.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$logFileObjects = @()


foreach($confirmation in $confirmationArray){

    $object = [PSCustomObject] @{
    confirmationNumber = $confirmation
    Keycode = getKeycode -confNumber $confirmation
    }

    $logFileObjects.Add($object) | Out-Null


    $object.confirmationNumber + " " +  $object.Keycode
}
```

Output

```
0000000091260759 System.Data.DataRow
0000000091308925 System.Data.DataRow
0000000091116609 System.Data.DataRow
```

Comment: This suggests that `$object.Keycode` isn't a primitive .NET type, but an instance of `[System.Data.DataRow]`, so you need to investigate why `getKeyCode` returns one.

Comment: Change the `getKeyCode` function to only return the column value you want rather than the entire row

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that makes sense to me but this is what I have at the minute - return Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver -Database mydb -Query $QueryConf - the sql itself selects two values so how do I specify which to return? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Cormac Assuming the column name is `Keycode`: `return (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver -Database mydb -Query $QueryConf).Item('Keycode')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MathiasR.Jessen

Change the `getKeyCode` function to only return the column value you want rather than the entire row:

```
return (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver -Database mydb -Query $QueryConf).Item('Keycode')
```